# How do I extend unix "ps -ef" command to see more info

Tags: unix, grep, ps

I need to grep process by information containing in CMD column, but this column strings is cut(limited)  and needed info is lost. Please suggest how can I enlarge string size allowed for CMD column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grepping in the `/proc` directory:

```
$ grep -a foo /proc/[0-9]*/cmdline
```

The `-a` switch says to treat binary files as text files, since `cmdline` files are recognized as binary.  `/proc/[0-9]*` says to only look at the directories mapped to PIDs.  When you find a match, you can use that output to get the PID from the directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-w` option twice to remove the width limit.

Comment: Aaaand that makes my answer look stupid.  I missed that option; good one.

Comment: I got next trying this: ps: illegal option -- w

Comment: @user590444: Exactly what OS and which `ps` version are you using?

Comment: Current system SunOS 5.1